# maximum value greater than a specific value? for each column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this data-frame:

```
      S    O        X1        X2        X3        X4
0   100  1.0  0.107455  0.446583  0.220452  0.105891
1   100  3.0  0.375586  0.314810  0.417982  0.974419
2   100  7.0  0.167457  0.555283  0.335208  0.152041
3   100  9.0  0.835885  0.213843  0.376132  0.605004
4   150  1.0  0.997843  0.837116  0.509243  0.993932
5   150  3.0  0.904277  0.276030  0.309795  0.623847
6   150  7.0  0.907843  0.387135  0.506080  0.685169
7   150  9.0   0.33937  0.990797  0.803394  0.385693
8   200  1.0  0.054206  0.105728  0.220876  0.399901
9   200  3.0  0.233063  0.972236  0.323389  0.322506
10  200  7.0   0.87344  0.395052  0.508753  0.962736
11  200  9.0  0.922502  0.471666  0.372094  0.380467
12  250  1.0  0.016137  0.478540  0.118725  0.815293
13  250  3.0  0.402824  0.466885  0.953571  0.133401
14  250  7.0  0.220363  0.134676  0.384890  0.931463
15  250  9.0   0.37158  0.429023  0.893135  0.297627
```

I want to see if for each value in `S` the maximum value of `X1, X2, X3, and X4`, separately for any of `O = 3, 7, or 9` is greater than the value of the same `S` and the corresponding `X` column but for `O = 1`.

For example: whether any of `0.375586`, `0.167457`, or `0.835885` is greater than `0.107455`. For each `S` and for each of the `X` columns.

Expected results:

```
    X1  100  1
0   X1  150  0
1   X1  200  1
2   X1  250  1
3   X2  100  …
4   X2  150  …
5   X2  200  …
6   X2  250  …
7   X3  100  …
8   X3  150  …
9   X3  200  …
10  X3  250  …
11  X4  100  …
12  X4  150  …
13  X4  200  …
14  X4  250  …
```

where `1` indicates "yes", and `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by column `S` and check for every group if the maximum value is not in the row for column `O = 1.0`.

Preparing the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import io

t = """
     S    O        X1        X2        X3        X4
0   100  1.0  0.107455  0.446583  0.220452  0.105891
1   100  3.0  0.375586  0.314810  0.417982  0.974419
2   100  7.0  0.167457  0.555283  0.335208  0.152041
3   100  9.0  0.835885  0.213843  0.376132  0.605004
4   150  1.0  0.997843  0.837116  0.509243  0.993932
5   150  3.0  0.904277  0.276030  0.309795  0.623847
6   150  7.0  0.907843  0.387135  0.506080  0.685169
7   150  9.0   0.33937  0.990797  0.803394  0.385693
8   200  1.0  0.054206  0.105728  0.220876  0.399901
9   200  3.0  0.233063  0.972236  0.323389  0.322506
10  200  7.0   0.87344  0.395052  0.508753  0.962736
11  200  9.0  0.922502  0.471666  0.372094  0.380467
12  250  1.0  0.016137  0.478540  0.118725  0.815293
13  250  3.0  0.402824  0.466885  0.953571  0.133401
14  250  7.0  0.220363  0.134676  0.384890  0.931463
15  250  9.0   0.37158  0.429023  0.893135  0.297627"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+')

df.head()
```

Output

```
     S    O        X1        X2        X3        X4
0  100  1.0  0.107455  0.446583  0.220452  0.105891
1  100  3.0  0.375586  0.314810  0.417982  0.974419
2  100  7.0  0.167457  0.555283  0.335208  0.152041
3  100  9.0  0.835885  0.213843  0.376132  0.605004
4  150  1.0  0.997843  0.837116  0.509243  0.993932
```

Using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html). The `X` columns contain the index for every group with the maximum value. For this to work the dataframe has to be [sorted](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by `['S','O']`.

```
df1 = df.groupby('S').apply(lambda a:a.reset_index(drop=True).idxmax())
df1
```

Output

```
     S  O  X1  X2  X3  X4
S                        
100  0  3   3   2   1   1
150  0  3   0   3   3   0
200  0  3   3   1   2   2
250  0  3   1   0   1   2
```

Compare the `X` columns to `0` with [`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) and [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the dataframe to get your desired result.

```
(df1
    .filter(like='X')
    .ne(0)
    .melt(ignore_index=False)
    .astype({'value': 'int'})
)
```

Output

```
    variable  value
S                  
100       X1      1
150       X1      0
200       X1      1
250       X1      1
100       X2      1
150       X2      1
200       X2      1
250       X2      0
100       X3      1
150       X3      1
200       X3      1
250       X3      1
100       X4      1
150       X4      0
200       X4      1
250       X4      1
```

---

Alternative solution for `pandas <1.1.0`

```
(df1
    .filter(like='X')
    .ne(0)
    .stack()
    .to_frame()
    .sort_index(level=[1,0])
    .reset_index()
    .astype({0: 'int'})
)
```

Comment: I added a solution for `pandas <1.1.0`.